# Write access violation when trying to modify array

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

The file from resources is passed to function Change which should XOR each byte value, but then I get write access violation error.

```
INT CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    HRSRC hRes = FindResource(NULL, L"FILE", RT_RCDATA);

    if (hRes == NULL)
    {
        // print error
    }

    DWORD resSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hRes);
    HGLOBAL resData = LoadResource(NULL, hRes);
    byte *file = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(LockResource(resData));

    Change(file, resSize);

    return 0;
}

void Change(byte *data, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        data[i] ^= 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the return value of `LockResource` to ensure that it wasn't null?

Comment: In memory window I can see that file variable has the bytes from my file.

Comment: Resources are in a read-only segment of the executable. You can't modify memory taken by the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources exist in read-only memory, you cannot write to them directly.

The only way to modify the contents of a resource is to use `UpdateResource()` (unless you `WriteFile()` directly to the executable file on disk), but you can't use either of those on a resource that belongs to an active running process, as the executable is locked by the OS.

So, the only way to do what you are attempting is to allocate a separate copy of the resource data in writable memory, and then you can do whatever you want with that copy, eg:

```
INT CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    HRSRC hRes = FindResource(NULL, L"FILE", RT_RCDATA);
    if (hRes == NULL)
    {
        // print error
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD resSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hRes);
        HGLOBAL resData = LoadResource(NULL, hRes);
        LPVOID resDataPtr = LockResource(resData);

        byte *copy = new byte[resSize];
        memcpy(copy, resDataPtr, resSize);
        Change(copy, resSize);
        delete[] copy;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually I found a way to alter resource that seemed locked, but I don't know if that would work here.  See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302660/how-can-i-change-the-style-of-a-control-clistbox-initialized-with-ddx-control/56316671#56316671