# How can I change the style of a control (CListBox) initialized with DDX_Control, before DDX_Control is called

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm modifying an existing project and a dialog has controls I am subclassing to theme differently in some cases (in other cases I will leave it entirely alone).  By the time `DDX_Control()` is called during `DoDataExchange()`, the hwnd for the `ListBox` already has styles applied.  Specifically, at this time even if I do `SetWindowLongPtr()`, the `LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` does not work.  By "does not work," I mean that although the style is applied, owner draw messages are not received by the CListBox.

Conversely, if I avoid the `DDX_Control()` and simply do a create, the ListBox does receive the messages and can be ownerdrawn.  But if I do this there are now two HWND, only one of which is returned by `GetDlgItem()`.  I believe I can make this work if necessary, but I wondered if there is a secret to intercept the HWND creation of the controls in the dialog (actually a CPropertyPage).

Below is code that doesn't work, with more commented code that "works" but isn't the way I wanted it to work, if possible.

```
void CMyPropertySheet::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    HWND hWndCtrl;
    pDX->m_pDlgWnd->GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1, &hWndCtrl);

    if (themed) {
        DWORD style = GetWindowLongPtr(hWndCtrl, GWL_STYLE) | LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED;
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWndCtrl, GWL_STYLE, style);
        DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_listbox);
        //RECT wr;
        //::GetWindowRect(hWndCtrl, &wr);
        //m_listbox.Create(style, wr, this, IDC_LIST1);
    } else {
        DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_listbox);
    }
```

I should probably add I tried subclassing the window, but it didn't help, and `CMyPropertySheet::PreSubclassWindow` wasn't soon enough, either.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/list-box-styles): *"LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED: Specifies that **the owner of the list box** is responsible for drawing its contents [...]. **The owner window receives** [...] a WM_DRAWITEM message when a visual aspect of the list box has changed."*

Comment: Some window creation flags have to be specified before the control is created, LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED is probably one of them. You have to modify the dialog template before it is loaded, or remove the listbox from dialog template and create it with `CListBox::Create` instead.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, yes, this is what I've tried to do.  However, after much effort getting to the DLGITEMTEMPLATE that contains the style, I cannot change it due to a "write access violation."

Comment: I can change the style of controls sucessfully in PreCreateWindow().

Comment: @TomTom there is no opportunity to do so with controls created by loading a dialog template.

Comment: Yes, changing the dialog template can be a nightmare. It's easier to read the existing listbox, copy its style, hide it, change its ID, then create a new listbox using the same style and same ID.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, I was able to do that, but it seems that the dialog still was "aware" of the old HWND and referred to it (GetDlgItem still returned that HWND). I don't know what problems that might have caused, but I chose not to go that route.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Maybe there something odd about application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some creation flags like `LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` and `LBS_SORT` are cached and modifying them afterwards have no effect. You have to change the template, or just make a duplicate of the listbox. Copy the style of the old listbox, then hide that listbox, change its ID, and create a new listbox based on the old one. You then have to remove `DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_listbox)`

The example below starts with a standard list which has its sort flag set. It duplicates the listbox and disables the sort option.

For simplicity this example avoids `LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED`, it uses `LBS_SORT` instead.

```
class CMyPropertyPage : public CPropertyPage
{
public:
    CListBox m_listbox;
    int m_listbox_index;

    CMyPropertyPage(int idd) : CPropertyPage(idd)
    {
        m_listbox_index = 1;
    }   

    void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
    {
        //This function is automatically called before 
        //CPropertyPage::OnInitDialog is complete
        //On the first call, IDC_LIST1 will point to the template listbox
        if(m_listbox.m_hWnd)
        {
            //m_listbox is ready, 
            //IDC_LIST1 will refer to the new listbox
            DDX_LBIndex(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_listbox_index);
        }
    }

    BOOL OnInitDialog()
    {
        CPropertyPage::OnInitDialog();

        CListBox* old_listbox = (CListBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1);
        if(old_listbox)
        {
            DWORD style = ~LBS_SORT & GetWindowLongPtr(old_listbox->m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
            CRect rc;
            old_listbox->GetWindowRect(&rc);
            ScreenToClient(&rc);
            old_listbox->SetDlgCtrlID(0);//change the old ID to something unused
            old_listbox->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE); //hide the old listbox
            m_listbox.Create(style | WS_BORDER, rc, this, IDC_LIST1);
            m_listbox.SetFont(GetFont());
        }

        ASSERT(m_listbox.GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_LIST1);
        m_listbox.AddString(L"2");
        m_listbox.AddString(L"1");
        m_listbox.AddString(L"0");

        UpdateData(FALSE);

        return TRUE;
    }
};

class CMyWinApp : public CWinApp
{
    BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CWinApp::InitInstance();
        CPropertySheet sh;
        CMyPropertyPage page(IDD_PAGE1);
        sh.AddPage(&page);
        sh.DoModal();
        return TRUE;
    }
} myapp;
```

Comment: Can you check what happens if you do HWND h = GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1)->GetSafeHwnd(); before this code, and after run this code:  HWND h2 = GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1)->GetSafeHwnd();  ASSERT(h2 != h);

Comment: It doesn't hit `ASSERT` in my case, works fine. It looks like `list->SetDlgCtrlID` is failing in your program. Try `SetWindowLongPtr(list->m_hWnd, GWL_ID, 9999);` then check the result for `int result = list->GetDlgCtrlID();` I tried it in a simple single thread program, maybe your setup is different.

Comment: How is your propertypage created?  Mine comes from a resource dialog.  As soon as domodal is called on the propertysheet, all the HWND are created.  And subclassing the listbox doesn't seem to change which HWND is returned by GetDlgItem.  Very curious, indeed.

Comment: It's just a standard propertysheet. See edit. Note there is a complication with `DoDataExchange`, it's explained in comment.

Comment: Ah, very nice.  I will assume this works.  I think both answers are valid, but I will give you credit since this was the path I wanted to follow before I gave up and started hacking templates.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm not sure I recommend this to anyone, but I did find a way to modify the template, finally.  I had to use VirtualProtect to unlock the memory of the template.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_pages.GetSize(); i++) {
    CPropertyPage* pPage = GetPage(i);
    PROPSHEETPAGE* tpsp = &pPage->m_psp;

    const DLGTEMPLATE* pTemplate;
    if (tpsp->dwFlags & PSP_DLGINDIRECT) {
        pTemplate = tpsp->pResource;
    } else {
        HRSRC hResource = ::FindResource(tpsp->hInstance, tpsp->pszTemplate, RT_DIALOG);
        if (hResource == NULL) return false;
        HGLOBAL hTemplate = LoadResource(tpsp->hInstance, hResource);
        if (hTemplate == NULL) return false;
        pTemplate = (LPCDLGTEMPLATE)LockResource(hTemplate);
        if (pTemplate == NULL) return false;
    }

    if (afxOccManager != NULL) {
        DLGITEMTEMPLATE *pItem = _AfxFindFirstDlgItem(pTemplate);
        DLGITEMTEMPLATE *pNextItem;
        BOOL bDialogEx = IsDialogEx(pTemplate);

        int iItem, iItems = DlgTemplateItemCount(pTemplate);

        for (iItem = 0; iItem < iItems; iItem++) {
            pNextItem = _AfxFindNextDlgItem(pItem, bDialogEx);
            DWORD dwOldProtect, tp;
            if (bDialogEx) {
                _DialogSplitHelper::DLGITEMTEMPLATEEX *pItemEx = (_DialogSplitHelper::DLGITEMTEMPLATEEX *)pItem;
                if (pItemEx->id == IDC_LIST1) {
                    if (VirtualProtect(&pItemEx->style, sizeof(pItemEx->style), PAGE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect)) {
                        pItemEx->style |= LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED;
                        VirtualProtect(&pItemEx->style, sizeof(pItemEx->style), dwOldProtect, &tp);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (pItem->id == IDC_LIST1) {
                    if (VirtualProtect(&pItem->style, sizeof(pItem->style), PAGE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect)) {
                        pItem->style |= LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED;
                        VirtualProtect(&pItem->style, sizeof(pItem->style), dwOldProtect, &tp);
                    }
                }
            }
            pItem = pNextItem;
        }
    }
}
return true;
```